# How do I correctly set permissions on a python install

Tags: python, linux, apache, permissions, easy-install

I'm installing a python module that I've created using easy-install. The python module is executed from the web via Apache/PHP, and therefore the apache user. I am currently working on it, and installing new versions every so often.

The issue is, when I run python setup.py install (as root) with a new version, the module is installed to site-packages as user root. This means that the user 'apache' is unable to use the new version and the website starts throwing back permissions errors to users.

I feel that there are several ways to go about dealing with this (for example changing Apache's user to be root, or installing the application as user apache), but I am not sure what is best practice.

Comment: I can can tell you what is ***not*** best practice, changing your apache config to run as root.  That shouldn't even be in consideration.

Comment: I should specify that this is on an internal network, not the internet, so that's not quite as stupid as it sounds, but definitely not a great option.